# Confused about usage of `std::istreambuf_iterator`

Tags: c++, iostream, istream, istream-iterator

I've implemented a deserialization routine for an object using the `<<` stream operator.  The routine itself uses an `istreambuf_iterator<char>` to extract characters from the stream one by one, in order to construct the object.

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to iterate over a stream using an `istream_iterator<MyObject>` and insert each object into a `vector`.  Pretty standard, except I'm having trouble getting the `istream_iterator` to *stop* iterating when it hits end-of-stream.  Right now, it just loops forever, even though calls to `istream::tellg()` indicate I'm at the end of the file.

Here's code to reproduce the problem:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() { }    
    Foo(char a_, char b_) : a(a_), b(b_) { }

    char a;
    char b;
};

// Output stream operator
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Foo& f)
{
    os << f.a << f.b;
    return os;
}

// Input stream operator
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)
{
    if (is.good()) 
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

        if (it != end) {
            f.a = *it++;
            f.b = *it++;
        }
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("foo.txt");
        ofs << Foo('a', 'b') << Foo('c', 'd');
    }

    std::ifstream ifs("foo.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<Foo> it(ifs);
    std::istream_iterator<Foo> end;
    for (; it != end; ++it) cout << *it << endl; // iterates infinitely
}
```

I know in this trivial example I don't even need istreambuf_iterator, but I'm just trying to simplify the problem so it's more likely people will answer my question.

So the problem here is that even though the `istreambuf_iterator` reaches the end of the stream buffer, the actual stream itself doesn't enter an `EOF` state.  Calls to `istream::eof()` return false, even though `istream::tellg()` returns the last byte in the file, and `istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)` compares true to `istreambuf_iterator<char>()`, meaning I'm definitely at the end of the stream.

I looked at the IOstreams library code to see exactly how it's determining whether an `istream_iterator` is at the end position, and basically it checks if `istream::operator void*() const` evaluates to `true`.  This istream library function simply returns:

```
return this->fail() ? 0 : const_cast<basic_ios*>(this);
```

In other words, it returns `0` (false) if the failbit is set.  It then compares this value to the same value in a default-constructed instance of `istream_iterator` to determine if we're at the end.

So I tried manually setting the failbit in my `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)` routine when the `istreambuf_iterator` compares true to the end iterator.  This worked perfectly, and properly terminated the loop.  But now I'm really confused.  It seems that `istream_iterator` *definitely* checks for `std::ios::failbit` in order to signify an "end-of-stream" condition.  But isn't that what `std::ios::eofbit` is for?  I thought `failbit` was for error conditions, like for example if the underlying file of an `fstream` couldn't be opened or something.

So, why do I need to call `istream::setstate(std::ios::failbit)` to get the loop to terminate?

Comment: looping forever indicates the stream has gone bad. The question is why?

Comment: @Martin, well, even if I replace the file stream with an `std::stringstream`, the same problem occurs.  So this can't be some kind of low-level file-related problem.

Comment: Reading @PigBen's answer. The reason is that at the outer level you are using istream_iterator (in the for_each) and istreambuf_iterator internally (operatro >>). You need to be consistent in your usage. USe istreambuf_iterators in both situations and it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use istreambuf_iterator, you are manipulating the underlying streambuf object of the istream object.  The streambuf object doesn't know anything about it's owner(the istream object), so calling functions on the streambuf object does not make changes to the istream object.  That's why the flags in the istream object are not set when you reach the eof.

Do something like this:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)
{
    is.read(&f.a, sizeof(f.a));
    is.read(&f.b, sizeof(f.b));
    return is;
}
```

**Edit**

I was stepping through the code in my debugger, and this is what I found.  istream_iterator has two internal data members. A pointer to the associated istream object, and an object of the template type (Foo in this case).  When you call ++it, it calls this function:

```
void _Getval()
{    // get a _Ty value if possible
    if (_Myistr != 0 && !(*_Myistr >> _Myval))
        _Myistr = 0;
}
```

_Myistr is the istream pointer, and _Myval is the Foo object.  If you look here:

```
!(*_Myistr >> _Myval)
```

That's where it calls your operator>> overload.  And it calls operator! on the returned istream object.  And as you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operatornot/), operator! only returns true if failbit or badbit are set, eofbit doesn't do it.

So, what happens next, if either failbit or badbit are set, the istream pointer gets NULL'd.  And the next time you compare the iterator to the end iterator, it compares the istream pointer, which is NULL on both of them.

Comment: I'd really prefer to use istreambuf_iterator, because it allows me to reuse the same routines generically with other types of iterators.  (For example, I can deserialize my object when it's stored in an `std::string` by using `string::iterator`.)  But I see what you're saying - the two sets of iterators aren't communicating.  So, why doesn't it work if I just manually call `istream::setstate(std::ios::eofbit)` on the `istream` object when the `istreambuf_iterator` reaches the end?

Comment: I would guess it's because when you compare an iterator to the end-of-stream iterator, it checks the failbit rather than the eofbit.  It makes sense to do this, because in normal operation of an istream object, (using operator>>), whenever the eofbit is set, the failbit is set as well.  However, the reverse is not always true, so it makes more sense to check the failbit.  In your function though, you should mimic the behaviour of operator>> and set both.

Answer (score 4):

Your outer loop—where you're checking for your `istream_iterator` to have reached its end—is tied to state stored in the `istream`'s inherited `ios_base`. The state on the `istream` represents the outcome of recent extraction operations performed against *the `istream` itself*, not the state of its underlying `streambuf`.

Your inner loop—where you're using `istreambuf_iterator` to extract characters from the `streambuf`—is using lower-level functions like [`basic_streambuf::sgetc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) (for [`operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)) and [`basic_streambuf::sbumpc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sbumpc) (for [`operator++`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/operator++)). Neither of those functions set state flags as a side effect, apart from the second one advancing [`basic_streambuf::gptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/gptr).

Your inner loop works fine, but it's implemented in a sneaky way packaged as it is, and it violates [the contract of `std::basic_istream& operator>>(std::basic_istream&, T&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2). If the function fails to extract an element as intended, it must call `basic_ios::setstate(badbit)` and, if it also encountered end-of-stream while extracting, it must also call `basic_ios::setstate(eofbit)`. Your extractor function sets neither flag when it fails to extract a `Foo`.

I concur with the other advice here to avoid use of `istreambuf_iterator` for implementing an extraction operator meant to work at the `istream` level. You're forcing yourself to do extra work to maintain the `istream` contract, which will cause other downstream surprises like the one that brought you here.

Answer (score 2):

In your `operator>>` you should set `failbit` any time you fail to successfully read a `Foo`.  Additionally you should set `eofbit` any time you detect end of file.  This could look like this:

```
// Input stream operator
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)
{
    if (is.good()) 
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

        std::ios_base::iostate err = it == end ? (std::ios_base::eofbit |
                                                  std::ios_base::failbit) :
                                                 std::ios_base::goodbit;
        if (err == std::ios_base::goodbit) {
            char a = *it;
            if (++it != end)
            {
                char b = *it;
                if (++it == end)
                    err = std::ios_base::eofbit;
                f.a = a;
                f.b = b;
            }
            else
                err = std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit;
        }
        if (err)
            is.setstate(err);
    }
    else
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

With this extractor, which sets failbit on failure to read, and eofbit on detecting eof of file, your driver works as expected.  Note especially that even if your outer `if (is.good())` fails, you still need to set `failbit`.  Your stream might be `!good()` because only `eofbit` is set.

You can slightly simplify the above by using an `istream::sentry` for the outer test.  If the `sentry` fails, it will set `failbit` for you:

```
// Input stream operator
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)
{
    std::istream::sentry ok(is);
    if (ok) 
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

        std::ios_base::iostate err = it == end ? (std::ios_base::eofbit |
                                                  std::ios_base::failbit) :
                                                 std::ios_base::goodbit;
        if (err == std::ios_base::goodbit) {
            char a = *it;
            if (++it != end)
            {
                char b = *it;
                if (++it == end)
                    err = std::ios_base::eofbit;
                f.a = a;
                f.b = b;
            }
            else
                err = std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit;
        }
        if (err)
            is.setstate(err);
    }
    return is;
}
```

The `sentry` also skips leading whitespace.  This may or may not be what you want.  If you don't want the sentry to skip leading whitespace you can construct it with:

```
    std::istream::sentry ok(is, true);
```

If the `sentry` detects end of file while skipping leading whitespace, it will set both `failbit` and `eofbit`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the two sets of stream iterators are interfearing with each other:

I got it working with this:

```
// Input stream operator
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Foo& f)
{
    f.a = is.get();
    f.b = is.get();

    return is;
}
```

Comment: okay - see my comments to PigBen.  I'd really prefer to use `std::istreambuf_iterator` because the use of iterators allows me to write generic routines that can work on any container, rather than routines which work only with streams.

Answer (score 0):

I think your end condition needs to use the `.equal()` method, instead of using the comparison operator.

```
for (; !it.equal(end); ++it) cout << *it << endl;
```

I usually see this implemented with a while loop instead of a for loop:

```
while ( !it.equal(end)) {
    cout << *it++ << endl;
}
```

I think those two will have the same effect, but (to me) the while loop is clearer.

Note: You have a number of other spots where you're using the comparison operator to check whether an iterator is at eof.  All of these should probably be switched to use `.equal()`.